# How do I view object error in AWS Lambda Node js

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I have an error on my AWS Lambda.

```
{
  "errorType": "object",
  "errorMessage": "[object Object]",
  "trace": []
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 9759e0c5-3ac7-494b-8970-d19b01981b32 Version: $LATEST
2021-07-16T08:46:51.907Z    9759e0c5-3ac7-494b-8970-d19b01981b32    ERROR   Invoke Error    {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"[object Object]","stack":["Error: [object Object]","    at _homogeneousError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:12:12)","    at postError (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:29:54)","    at done (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:56:7)","    at fail (/var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:68:7)","    at /var/runtime/CallbackContext.js:104:16","    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)"]}
END RequestId: 9759e0c5-3ac7-494b-8970-d19b01981b32
REPORT RequestId: 9759e0c5-3ac7-494b-8970-d19b01981b32  Duration: 335.31 ms Billed Duration: 336 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 69 MB  Init Duration: 157.54 ms
```

I was wondering how do I view the errorMessage `[object Object]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope it's not too late. I had the same issue and I solved it by following this instruction from the following link:

"You must turn the myErrorObj object into a JSON string before calling callback to exit the function. Otherwise, the myErrorObj is returned as a string of "[object Object]"."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html

I simply passing the "error" object as JSON.stringify(error) solved the problem in my case.